# Using Multiple jquery versions for plugins

Tags: jquery

I am trying to setup a way to use multiple version of jquery.  I am currently trying to make a old site responsive using bootstrap and need the newest version of jquery but the site has a couple sliders on it that use an older version of jquery and they new version breaks them.  I have done some research and believe that I am close but just not sure what I am not doing right.  How do you setup this up so that I can tell jquery to only use the old version for the plugin, the code for the silder plugin is massive and I don't want to change "$" 784 times through the code.

Here is my current setup. I am using a CMS and these are nested within different controls.

Control that generates javascript on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/lib/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var jq181 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery-custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/simple-expand.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my jquery file I placed it here because it was somewhat large: http://pastebin.com/ej8AKPHy

I think I can use this code to achieve what I want to do I am just not sure how to setup it up or what code needs to go inside it.

```
 var jq181 = jQuery.noConflict(true); 
 (function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {

  });
 }(jq181));
```

So does the entire jquery file need to go inside this function or just parts?

Comment: why don't you try the new jQuery version with the [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hzxtwjta/1/

Comment: Wanna post again as the answer please.  Thanks a bunch this worked great!

Answer (score 1):

One possible option for you instead of using multiple version of jQuery is to try out the [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/).

The problem you could be facing is some of the plugins might be using methods that are removed in jQuery 1.9 when a lot of deprecated was cleaned up. To enable backward compatibility jQuery has introduced the migration plugin which will restore those removed functionality. So try it out

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery-custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/simple-expand.js"></script>
```

Comment: So this worked great but in my situation I migrated to 1.8.1 since the plugin only was supported on 1.2.3 and up and they person before me was using 1.8.1 and it seems to work.